Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError
i have created a xamarin.forms app. the target android version was android 9. and it worked well. but then i got a new tablet, it says in the settings that it is android 13, but when i connect it to visual studio, it says android 8.1 api 27. the problem is that on this tab the app doesn't work. when i debug on it, i get this exception: Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError:** 'no non-static method "Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;)V"'
i get this exception on this line RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppLifecycleCallbacks()); in the MainActivity.cs in the xamarin.Android project. i tried changing the target android version to 8.1 and rebuilt my solution and restarted my vs, but still the same. what can i do?
